# Voting reversal

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Today I got -80 reputation points from voting reversal on Stack Overflow. I know why it happened, but I just want to confirm what will happen if some of the answers given by one user are exactly what another user wanted. And on getting his problem solved, the user upvoted the answer.

So will this also account for voting reversal? But in reality answers would have helped another user, so would it be right to reverse the votes given by that user?

Comment: The voting reversal script is pretty conservative to prevent false positives. Generally speaking, it is highly unlikely that you gave 8 answers that were personally helpful to someone on the same day and within a couple hours. What more likely happened was that you gave one, and the user then went on and upvoted a bunch of your others, out of thanks. Thats frowned upon here.

Comment: Also wether that would be "right" is irrelevant. The system is an algorhitm and cannot distinguish between targeted voting (considered abuse) and very unlikely circumstances that you describe.

Comment: I also believe that the "false" positives that do happen, is heavily outweighed by the amount of correct reversals and amount of time the script is saving mods and those who would otherwise handle it.

Comment: You would have to provide 8 answers to the same user that were all useful, within a 24 hour period. That seems highly unlikely to me, and would probably signify other problems, like a user not being able to solve any of their own problems, or you and said user colluding on questions and answers, or even you using a sockpuppet account to ask questions, then posting the answer from your main account.

Comment: So that means if they are really helpful to user. No matter what they will get reversed?

Comment: Yes. Tell your friends to stop trying to help you out by voting up all of your answers. The system reverses such votes. They are considered illegitimate. All quite well explained in [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).

Comment: For normal people not trying to game the system, this is such a rare occurence as to be almost meaningless in its impact.

Comment: I have confirmed with all of my friends and none of them has done it. It may be some other person who did that

Comment: @VivekMishra - There is no point in discussing who did it or for what reasons. The point is that the system considered your reputation as *fraud* and corrected it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Today I got -80 reputation from voting reversal on stack overflow

That means that 8 upvotes on your answers were given by the same user within a 24-hour period (at least, most likely a lot quicker then that).

The exact mechanisms of the serial voting reversal script that runs every day are unknown to prevent gaming it, but suffice to say it is pretty conservative to prevent false positives.

> I know why it happened but I just want to confirm what will happen if some of the answers given by one user are exactly what another user wanted.

In your case, the notion that 8 of your answers were helpful to a specific user within a single day is highly unlikely. What more likely happened (assuming good faith) is that a user found an answer of yours very helpful, and decided to "thank" you by upvoting a bunch of your others. That's considered targeted voting and very frowned upon.

> And on getting his problem solved, user upvoted the answer. So will this will also account for voting reversal?

The serial voting reversal is a script that runs every day. As an automated algorithm, it cannot distinguish between the targeting voting it is trying to prevent and very rare edge cases (like 8 answers being useful in a day). In this case, the good (catching a lot of actual serial voting) heavily outweighs the bad.

> But in reality answers would have helped another user, so would it be
>   right to reverse the votes given by that user?

Given the massive potential for abuse if we didn't have it, yes, definitely.