# What should / can / may I do when losing reputation points due to serial voting?

Tags: support, serial-voting, voting-correction

I went through these posts (top five):

1. [Is this serial up-voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204548/is-this-serial-up-voting)
2. [Is a serial voter notified when serial voting is reversed if voting didn't cost reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381248/is-a-serial-voter-notified-when-serial-voting-is-reversed-if-voting-didnt-cost)
3. [Voting reversal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319068/voting-reversal)
4. [Serial voting: reversal problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295434/serial-voting-reversal-problem)
5. [What should I do when I get serial up voting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386093/what-should-i-do-when-i-get-serial-up-voting)

I lost 130 reputation points due to serial voting today:

Serial voting is defined as getting upvotes in a defined time by the same user?!
→ from the linked page:

[image]

Where can I intervene to check if this is real serial voting?

Some considerations:

- If there is a suspicion of illegally behaviour with persons voting on persons and not answer efforts, then the staff should limit the upvotes and downvotes per user on another user per day. This will limit the chance of serial voting.
- If one user is very good and answers all questions, he/she will get points in series. → Is this then serial voting?
- To evolve and make things better in the future, a little more information would be very kind, because getting the information of -130 reputation points if it is unjustified is neither clear nor causal!

Comment: You can't stop people from serially upvoting you. there's literally nothing you can do there. Someone upvoted your posts (and likely posts for other people) and were caught to have been committing voting fraud, and the votes were reversed as a result.

Comment: *"I lost 130 reputation points due to serial voting today:"* You didn't lose anything; you *gained* 130 reputation from illegitimate votes, and those votes were **reversed** today. Those votes weren't legitimate to start with, so you had nothing to lose.

Comment: There are two (non practical) things you can do - join SO (as company) to be able to ocassionally get access to such info and indeed stop (or don't start) serial (down-)voting to avoid visible change on reputation points on the reversal.

Comment: @Larnu. Thank you very much for your valuable comment. I have a question: Who defines if these votes were illegitimate votes and where is the definition?

Comment: Some of that is covered in the message you got for the reputation change: [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) - *"No matter the cause, this sort of voting targeted at a person is not permitted - always remember to **vote for the post, not the person who wrote it.**"*

Comment: @Makoto that dupe target is about serial downvotes, this question is about serial upvoting (I'm sure there's a dupe target for that somewhere).

Comment: This  is really strange. But my question has nothing to do with that one  as duplicated marked "What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?"

Comment: the answer is the same. there's nothing you can do aside from what you've done. You received a sudden flood of upvotes, you waited for them to be reversed, and they were reversed.

Comment: You can't contest whether or not they were serial upvotes, that investigation has already occurred.

Comment: If it is any consolation: this concerned a number of accounts, all of them victims of someone that went through profiles and upvoted a lot of their posts in series. In fact, I lost 12 votes this way too, and some of the users targeted lost a _lot_ more. It sometimes happens, but you don't need to be concerned about this being common or that you did anything wrong.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters. This is a consolation. Thank you very much for your words. Obvious things become obvious after making some experience!!!

Comment: @TarJae If it is any consolation, I lost about 1.5k votes today.

Comment: @akrun point 2 of my considerations in my post: "If one user is very good and answers all questions, he will get points in series. -> Is this then serial voting?"

Comment: @TarJae I don't know how they judge voting criteria as legit or not.  Maybe someone frequently using R voting for Python tag may not be considered as a serial voting and viceversa.   But, those things are very rare as I only check for R tag Q& A and votes).

Comment: Also, I looked at some other users rep as well.  Many of them lost points today.

Comment: I'm reopening this, as [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252270/208273) is a very different question (relating to how to get a reversal upon seeing serial of votes, not reversals of said votes that have already occurred), and the answer is also irrelevant to this situation.

Comment: @41686d6564 stands w. Palestine. Thank you very much for this link. I think this post which was after my post asks a different quesiton on the same issue: "So are we talking about a voting ring or similar?" What's the benefit of contributing seemingly random votes?"  Why did it take a long time to occur? Therefore it is a helpful post, but does not answer my question directly.

Comment: You can't lose what you were not supposed to have, it is merely a correction of the bookkeeping. But I recently was made to realise the fact that serial upvoting makes people artificially hit the reputation cap in a day, so you really do lose reputation points once it all gets reversed - the ones you missed out on that day because you hit the cap. It sucks, but luckily you have plenty to spare. Probably the best thing to do here is to learn to not care as much.

Comment: In [the duplicate target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419983/), approximately 1,600 reputation points were "lost".

Comment: I do not understand how my question could be a duplicate of a question the was asked after my question! Mine was 19 h before and the suspected duplicate was asked 15 hours before? If any dulplicate, then mine should be the original one?

Comment: @TarJae The age of a question isn't really relevant to whether it should be used as a duplicate target, or not. It's much more relevant which question is clearer, and which one has better answers.

Comment: OK Thanks @cigien. Allthough I believe this counteracts the idea of duplicates! e.g If the latter one is better, then it is a better question and not duplicate. But anyway...

Comment: @TarJae The idea behind using the better question as duplicate target is that all the duplicates will act as sign posts to lead future users with the same problem to the best questions where they will then find an answer.

Comment: When the question is closed as duplicate it doesn't mean that a similar question was asked before, but that there are answers to this question elsewhere. It can be a newer question too. Do not add meta-commentary to your question please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What should / can / may I do when losing reputation points due to serial voting

As far as I am aware there is nothing you can do that will make any difference.   And there is nothing you can do to obtain the evidence you would need to investigate this for yourself.

Investigation and reversal of serial upvotes is "above" the level of the diamond moderators.

The only thing you could do would be to lodge a complaint via the contact form.  However, I doubt that would achieve anything.

I'm not saying that the staff "don't care".  I'm sure they do.  But you simply have nothing you can present to them as evidence that a reversal was a mistake.

(Unless you have a back-channel to one of the alleged serial up-voters!)

---

It would be nice if there was more information about which of one's answers lost upvotes (or downvotes) due to a reversal.  But I can't see how it would be possible without violating people's privacy; i.e. de-anonymizing votes.  (And IMO that is a more important consideration that my so-called "need" to know who voted for my question or answer.)