# Can Stack Overflow detect bully users?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, low-quality-posts, downvote-reason

I suspect all of my questions are downvoted by an offended user. I never left any comment for downvote. It could be my paranoia though.

Just out of curiosity, are there algorithms to detect such behavior?

For example, I know the user uses multiple accounts.

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419980/what-should-can-may-i-do-when-losing-reputation-points-due-to-serial-voting

Comment: If you “know” that a user uses multiple accounts, please do not forget to raise a flag for moderator attention, describing how you know about the multiple accounts and links to the profiles.

Comment: In the last 2 years you received exactly 2 downvotes. So unless you are deliberately deleting your questions, after you receive a downvote, your reputation history doesn’t reflect your claim you are being targeted by a toxic user. Deleting a question after receiving a downvote is not positive behavior.

Comment: So it was actually 3 downvotes in 2+ years, I still suspect, your experience being different then your reputation history is due to questions being deleted

Comment: I count *six* in 2024, @SecurityHound ... That's only 3 months. (Do not read into this comment as supporting the OP's claim.)

Comment: I missed the +8 events, my apologies

Comment: What on earth.. you have 26k, and most you lost in last half year or so is 150 on a bunch of bounties (while earning an order of magnitude more on upvotes).